# Are my friends immune to the harmful effects of radiation?

Tags: fallout-4

As I travel around the wasteland, there are times when the geiger counter unavoidably starts ticking rapidly, and I need to pop a Rad-X, or even put on a Hazmat Suit. Some of my companions will remark on this as well, however, I'm not sure if they're actually affected by the radiation.

Does exposure to radiation have an effect on the health of my companions? If so, is it the same for all of them, or, for example, are robots immune? What about Synths? Are Strong and Hancock healed by it?

Comment: as far as what effects they have on your companions short term I don't know, but as you probably figured out they can't die. So long term health issues are unlikely and I would guess that they slowly heal away radiation or all their radiation problems disappear when they are knockout. But this is of course speculation.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually hurt the companions they just mention it a lot so you don't have to worry about it killing them or something. For role-playing purposes you could leave the human companions & dog at home for areas like the glowing sea or put the human ones in power armor if you are one of those that likes role-playing like that which is what I do. Here is a link where they discussed it not many comments though. https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/492378265877233598/

Answer (score 1):

No NPCs have radiation damage applied to them from the environment (gamma gun and etc is exempt), with the exception of feral ghoul enemies. Environmental radiation heals them. Your companions do not "knock out" due to environmental radiation damage or receive healing effects.

Comment: Funnily enough, the synth companions' reaction chatter is more concerned about you than them! So at least that's realistic.

Comment: "gamma gun and etc"... what else is in that et cetera? I image they just heal the radiation damage after a fight light regular health?

Comment: I mean any radiation damage is inflicted as regular damage, and I'd assume it is healed as usual. But enivronmental radiation and radiation damage are treated differently for NPCs.

Comment: Companions can't die... so doubt they are affected by radiation.

Comment: They can however, take damage. Their "death" is replaced with them sitting down and complaining :)